# Polyomino generator

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, connected-figure

**Write a program that prints the shapes of** [one-sided polyominoes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polyomino).

Given input 4 (tetrominos), a sample output would be:

```
 *   *         *     *
 *   *    **   **   **  *
**   **   **    *   *  ***  ****
```

You are not restricted with respect to orientation, ordering or layout as long as polyominoes are not connected and not duplicated. (E.g. you can print the shapes in a column rather than a row)

Provide code that inputs a number from 3 to 6 and outputs the one-sided polyominoes of that size. The expected number of polyominoes output are 2, 7, 18, and 60 for 3, 4, 5, and 6 as inputs respectively.

Shortest code wins, present your solution for number 4.

Comment: I'm a little confused. The goal is a program that can print all triominos through all hexominos?

Comment: Actually you need to write program that takes number and outputs all polyominoes of that number.

Comment: @ralu Could you please clarify that in your post? The "_Provide code that accepts number from 3 to 6 and displays proper polyomino_" bit makes it seem like you only want triominos-hexominos.

Comment: You forgot the T tetromino.  I take it you mean "one-sided" polyominos?

Comment: It's *polyominoes*, not *polynomials* :D

Comment: @Lowjacker, oops. Mea culpa. Guess which of the two words I type more frequently...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Python, <strike>398</strike> 392 chars

```
n=input()
r=range
T=lambda P:set(p-min(p.real for p in P)-min(p.imag for p in P)*1j for p in P)
A=[]
for i in r(1<<18):
 P=[k%3+k/3*1j for k in r(18)if i>>k&1]
 C=set(P[:1])
 for x in P:[any(p+1j**k in C for k in r(4))and C.add(p)for p in P]
 P=T(P)
 if not(C^P or P in A or len(P)-n):
  for y in r(4):print''.join(' *'[y+x*1j in P] for x in r(6))
  A+=[T([p*1j**k for p in P])for k in r(4)]
```

Polyominos are represented as sets of complex numbers representing the cells of the polyomino.  For example, T takes a polyomino and translates it so the minimum real and imaginary coordinates are 0.

The outer loop iterates through all 2^18 3x6 grids, generating a potential polyomino P, making sure P is connected (by computing C, the part of the polyomino connected to P[0]), checking that P isn't in the list A of previously found polyominos, and verifying that P has exactly n cells.  Any new polyomino is added to A in all 4 rotations.

It takes two minutes or so to run to completion.  Here's the result for n=4:

```
**    
*     
*     

*     
**    
*     

**    
**    


 *    
**    
*     

*     
*     
**    

*     
**    
 *    

****
```

Comment: This is just Printing out `****` when I try it. And `n` is a string so I get unsupported operand… error on line 10. Do you know how to fix it?

Answer (score 3):

### Ruby, <strike>266</strike> <strike>241</strike> 320 (227 without reflections)

Given the input restrictions, it's easier to just use a bitmap of all the polyominos.

```
puts [%w[13 3],%w[1vqxip 1s9b3b],%w[1j85qxc81ax0oxld 1db08aq5w1vdul13 172qaw25hgn8jn5t],%w[5l91ancci09g0iuurrdbkbrsl58jjiodia8irxlivoufjjse42o4l8hlcz 3qbvfj70ksz14cngk9exust0w1qjshykauo6yvyyn3j6oefyy1xc58hsoj 26c0102a8vw34q88pktwlkepxzcslicg6ydtrz4zhyyutd4bukh73187qb]][gets.hex-3].map{|n|n.to_i(36).to_s(2).tr'10','* '}
```

Old version (outputs just the free polyominoes):

```
puts [%w[13 3],%w[9iz3 a5z],%w[cfu9zai70z b3tsb0pge1 12t8eks810j],%w[5wgmz704fjqc593xfwrmkwb7k0j9ztr31v fr8weq5t88qdxp93hit2fh8899qcbr2a9f 10r578ajcw2n15dwywsm0ep601kiv41cco3]][gets.hex-3].map{|n|n.to_i(36).to_s(2).tr'10','* '}
```

Output for n=4:

```
** **  *    *  ****  **   *
**  ** *** ***      **  ***
```

Comment: @Ventero: Thanks. Wasn't sure whether it would give an advantage, since the bitmap is split in 10 parts.

Comment: Use `%w` notation to save about 10 characters (e.g. `%w[13 3]`). Also, since the input is a single digit, you can use `gets.hex` to save another char.

Comment: Where are missing reflections?

Comment: @ralu: I've added them, but if you want the reflections, you should say so in the question.

Answer (score 1):

#### Golfscript, 221 chars

Also 221 bytes. Inspired by Lowjacker's approach, but moderately different in actual implementation (and produces one-sided rather than two-sided polyominos).

Because some of the characters used, while valid Unicode codepoints (and one byte each in UTF-8), are non-printable, I present the base-64 encoding of the script:

```
fidAQEAVRRVALVs9TUZFUwhgA0BrdjVXGm4VOl8aDgMZfBdoVQQzNk0YLQ9eXCciBhwQH0ADDW9E
KlomSXgoLBxxI1oEeB9XPm51GF43bHBKQzl3WQ5vXTJCTABfEz4bJBlaWX0XL2QVDF5ZXFw5BxpF
IzNUKmUtYwEEfQEKckMSbjAlQmhYHShQaAtjK1QFbnt5WQokFkNkHgNlL35cXCU6Hj8nIkAiLz0x
MjdiYXNlIDRiYXNlWzNdL3tbKVxbMl0vLi0xJUAqXXt7eyIgKiI9fSVuK30vbn0vfS8=
```

And the script itself with the magic strings substituted:

```
~"@@@Magic@strings@go@here""@"/=127base 4base[3]/{[)\[2]/.-1%@*]{{{" *"=}%n+}/n}/}/
```

Example execution:

```
$ golfscript.rb poly.gs <<<"4"
****


***
*

*
***

**
**


***
 *


**
 **

 **
**
```