# Can you fold a hexomino into a cube?

Tags: code-golf, ascii-art, kolmogorov-complexity, geometry

One of my kid's favorite toys is [a set like this](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000CBSNRY).  Actually its one of my favorite toys - I've been playing with it and its been giving me some PPCG challenge ideas.  Here's one:

Write a program or function that takes an ASCII line drawing as input and decides whether or not it folds into a cube.

#### Input

Input will consist of exactly one hexomino built from squares like this:

```
+-+
| |
+-+
```

For example a valid input heximino is:

```
+-+
| |
+-+-+-+-+
| | | | |
+-+-+-+-+
  | |
  +-+
```

#### Output

- A truthy value if the hexomino can be folded into a cube, or
- A falsey value otherwise.

To save us a bit of work, wikipedia has nice graphics of:

- All 35 hexominoes:

[image]

- All 11 hexominoes that fold into cubes:

[image]

#### Notes

- Input hexominoes may have any rotation or reflection, not just those shown in the images above
- Input hexominoes may have leading spaces, but will be correctly aligned with respect to themselves
- Input hexominoes may have trailing space at the end of lines and trailing newlines at the end of input

Comment: Can you explain why there is an image-processing tag here ? Neither the question, nor the answer will have to do any kind of image processing to solve the challenge.

Comment: Clarification about leading/trailing space: are unnecessary leading/trailing spaces on each row and unnecessary newlines allowed in input ? Should I be able to manage a 1000+ chars input?

Comment: @edc65 yes you should expect the unnecessary white space you describe. 1000 chars max input size seems reasonable - I'll edit that in

Comment: Hmm. I wonder how many cube hexominoes can be squeezed, juxtaposed, on a printed page?

Answer (score 7):

## [PMA/Snails](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/47495/30688), 130

```
.!(z\ |o{c..!(z\ }3){w=(..!(z\ )|b..!(z\ )o{..!(z\ }2|c{..!(z\ }1,2w..!(z\ )|w{..!(z\ }1,2c..!(z\ }4o..!(z\ )(..!(z\ )|n..!(z\ )`2
```

or more "readably",

```
?
.!(z\  | o{c..!(z\ }3  )
{w =( ..!(z\ ) | b ..!(z\ ) o {..!(z\ }2  | c {..!(z\ }1,2w..!(z\ ) | w {..!(z\ }1,2c..!(z\  }4
o  ..!(z\ ) ( ..!(z\ ) | n ..!(z\ ) `2
```

Unusually, a problem came along that can be handled by the limited amount of features implemented so far. The `!(z\ )` pattern determines that the current position is at the space in the middle of a square using a negative assertion that there is a space in some "octilinear" direction. The general idea is to check for a pattern that places a square at each of the 5 necessary locations relative to the square that the match starts on. Also, it needs to check that it is not in a 2x2 block of squares. Before the program would work, I had to fix a bug with the parsing of parentheses.

If the hexomino does not map a cube, `0` is printed. If it does, some positive integer is printed (number of matches).

I adapted [this polyomino generator](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/2237/30688) to create all possible test cases:

```
n=input()
r=range
T=lambda P:set(p-min(p.real for p in P)-min(p.imag for p in P)*1j for p in P)
A=[]
for i in r(1<<18):
 P=[k%3+k/3*1j for k in r(18)if i>>k&1]
 C=set(P[:1])
 for x in P:[any(p+1j**k in C for k in r(4))and C.add(p)for p in P]
 P=T(P)
 if not(C^P or P in A or len(P)-n):
  #for y in r(4):print''.join(' *'[y+x*1j in P] for x in r(6))
  o = [ [' ']*13 for _ in r(9)]
  for y in r(4):
   for x in r(6):
    if y+x*1j in P: X=2*x;Y=2*y; o[Y][X]=o[Y+2][X]=o[Y][X+2]=o[Y+2][X+2]='+'; o[Y][X+1]=o[Y+2][X+1]='-';o[Y+1][X+2]=o[Y+1][X]='|'
  print '\n'.join(map(''.join,o))
  A+=[T([p*1j**k for p in P])for k in r(4)]
```

Comment: hahahahahahahah more "readably"

Answer (score 5):

## Ruby, <s>173 148 145</s> 143 bytes

```
h=->b,c{[c.count(c.max),c.count(c.min),3].max*2<b.max-b.min}
->s{x=[];y=[];i=j=0
s.bytes{|e|e==43&&x<<i|y<<j;i=e<32?0*j+=1:i+1}
h[x,y]||h[y,x]}
```

Latest change: `/2` on right side of `<` replaced by `*2`on left side. Allows elimination of one set of`()`

**Explanation**

The code is in two parts: a main unnamed function that does the parsing, and an auxiliary unnamed function assigned to the variable `h` that does the checking.

The main function scans bytewise through the string, adding the x and y coordinates `i,j` of all `+` symbols found to `x[]` and `y[]`. It then calls `h` twice. The first time it assumes the hexomino is horizontal (`x[]` contains the lengths and `y[]` the widths) and the second time it assumes it is vertical.

**The function `h` takes the lengthwise coordinates in array `b` then the widthwise coordinates in array `c`.** It calculates the length (in squares) by the expression  `(b.max.b.min)/2`. If this is less than or equal to 3, the hexomino should be evaluated in the other direction so `h` returns `false`.

Inspection of the hexominos will show that if the length is 4, **those hexominos that will fold into a cube have no more than 2 squares (3 `+` symbols) in the first and last row**. Most of the squares are concentrated on the middle row, which will become the equator of the cube. This condition turns out to be necessary and sufficient for a hexomino of length 4 that will fold into a cube.

There is only one hexomino of length 5 that will fold into a cube. It has 3 squares (4 `+` symbols) in its first and last rows. All other hexominos of length 5 have 5 or more `+` symbols in either the first or last row.

There is only one hexomino of length 6. It has 7 `+` symbols on each row.

**Putting all this together, it is sufficient to check that the length of the hexomino is greater than 3, and the number of `+` symbols on the first and last rows (whichever is higher) is less than the length.**

**Ungolfed in test program**

```
#checking function as explained in text
h=->b,c{[c.count(c.max),c.count(c.min),3].max<(b.max-b.min)/2}

#main function for parsing
f=->s{
  x=[]                 #separate assignments required, 
  y=[]                 #otherwise we get 2 pointers to the same array
  i=j=0                #start coordinates 0,0
  s.bytes{|e|          #scan string bytewise
    e==43&&x<<i|y<<j     #if byte is a + symbol (ascii 43) add the coordinates to arrays x and y
    i=e<32?0*j+=1:i+1    #if byte is before ascii 32 assume newline, increment j and zero i. Otherwise increment i
  }
  h[x,y]||h[y,x]       #call h twice, with x and y in each possible order
}
    


#VALID INPUTS
puts f["
+-+
| |
+-+-+-+-+
| | | | |
+-+-+-+-+
| |
+-+"]

puts f["
+-+
| |
+-+-+-+-+
| | | | |
+-+-+-+-+
  | |
  +-+"]

puts f["
+-+
| |
+-+-+-+-+
| | | | |
+-+-+-+-+
    | |
    +-+"]
puts f["
+-+
| |
+-+-+-+
| | | |
+-+-+-+-+
    | | |
    +-+-+"]

puts f["
+-+
| |
+-+-+-+-+
| | | | |
+-+-+-+-+
      | |
      +-+"]

puts f["
    +-+
    | |
+-+-+-+-+
| | | | |
+-+-+-+-+
    | |
    +-+"]
puts f["
    +-+
    | |
+-+-+-+
| | | |
+-+-+-+-+
    | | |
    +-+-+"]


puts f["
  +-+
  | |
+-+-+-+-+
| | | | |
+-+-+-+-+
    | |
    +-+"]
puts f["
  +-+
  | |
+-+-+-+
| | | |
+-+-+-+-+
    | | |
    +-+-+"]  
puts f["
+-+-+
| | |
+-+-+-+
  | | |
  +-+-+-+
    | | |
    +-+-+"]

puts f["
  +-+-+-+
  | | | |
  +-+-+-+-+-+
      | | | |
      +-+-+-+
"]


#INVALID INPUTS

puts f["
  +-+-+-+
  | | | |
  +-+-+-+
  | | | |
  +-+-+-+
"]


puts f["
  +-+-+-+-+-+-+
  | | | | | | |
  +-+-+-+-+-+-+

"]


puts f["
  +-+-+
  | | |
  +-+-+
  | |
  +-+
  | |
  +-+
  | |
  +-+
  | |
  +-+
"]

puts f["
  +-+-+-+-+-+
  | | | | | |
  +-+-+-+-+-+
    | |
    +-+
"]

puts f["
      +-+
      | |
  +-+-+-+-+-+
  | | | | | |
  +-+-+-+-+-+
"]

puts f["
  +-+-+-+-+
  | | | | |
  +-+-+-+-+-+
        | | |
        +-+-+"]

puts f["
  +-+-+-+-+
  | | | | |
  +-+-+-+-+
      | | |
      +-+-+
"] 


puts f["
  +-+-+-+-+
  | | | | |
  +-+-+-+-+
  | | | |
  +-+ +-+
"]

puts f["
 +-+   +-+
 | |   | |
 +-+-+-+-+
 | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+
"]

puts f["
   +-+-+
   | | |
 +-+-+-+-+
 | | | | |
 +-+-+-+-+
"]

puts f["
  +-+
  | |
  +-+
  | |
  +-+-+-+-+
  | | | | |
  +-+-+-+-+
"]

puts f["
  +-+
  | |
  +-+-+-+
  | | | |
  +-+-+-+
  | |
  +-+
  | |
  +-+
"]

puts f["
  +-+
  | |
+-+-+-+
| | | |
+-+-+-+
| |
+-+
| |
+-+"]

puts f["
  +-+-+
  | | |
  +-+-+
  | |
  +-+-+
  | | |
  +-+-+
    | |
    +-+
"]

puts f["
  +-+-+-+
  | | | |
  +-+-+-+-+
    | | | |
    +-+-+-+
"]

puts f["
  +-+-+-+
  | | | |
  +-+-+-+
      | |
      +-+-+
      | | |
      +-+-+
"]


puts f["
  +-+-+-+
  | | | |
  +-+-+-+-+
      | | |
      +-+-+
        | |
        +-+
"]
```

Comment: pentonimo → hexonimo in your text?

Answer (score 3):

## JavaScript (ES6), 443 <s>431</s>

*Edit* bug fix, problem during input parse, removing blank columns

```
F=t=>(a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h=0,M=Math.min,
t=t.split('\n').filter(r=>r.trim()>''),
t=t.map(r=>r.slice(M(...t.map(r=>r.search(/\S/))))),
t.map((r,i)=>i&1&&[...r].map((_,j)=>j&1&&r[j-1]==r[j+1]&t[i-1][j]==t[i+1][j]&r[j-1]=='|'
&&(y=i>>1,x=j>>1,z=y*5,w=x*5,a|=1<<(z+x),e|=1<<(w+y),b|=1<<(4+z-x),f|=1<<(4+w-y),c|=1<<(20-z+x),g|=1<<(20-w+y),d|=1<<(24-z-x),h|=1<<(24-w-y)
))),~[1505,2530,3024,4578,252,6552,2529,4577,2499,4547,7056].indexOf(M(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)))
```

That's very long, and even longer as parsing input is a big part of the task.

What I do is verifyng if the given input is one of the 11 foldable hexominoes.

Each foldable hexomino can be mapped to some 5x5 bitmap (up to 8 different, with simmetry and rotations). Taken the bitmaps as 25bit number, I have found the min values for the 11 noted hexominoes, using the following code (with very simple input format)

```js
h=[ // Foldable hexominoes
'o\noooo\no', ' o\noooo\n o', // pink
'o\noooo\n   o', ' o\noooo\n  o', 'ooo\n  ooo', 'oo\n oo\n  oo', //blue
'o\noooo\n o', 'o\noooo\n  o', 'oo\n ooo\n o', 'oo\n ooo\n  o', 'o\nooo\n  oo' // gray
]
n=[]
h.forEach(t=>(
  a=[],
  t.split('\n')
    .map((r,y)=>[...r]
      .map((s,x)=>s>' '&&(
         a[0]|=1<<(y*5+x),a[1]|=1<<(x*5+y),  
         a[2]|=1<<(y*5+4-x),a[3]|=1<<(x*5+4-y),  
         a[4]|=1<<(20-y*5+x),a[5]|=1<<(20-x*5+y),  
         a[6]|=1<<(24-y*5-x),a[7]|=1<<(24-x*5-y))
     )
  ),
n.push(Math.min(...a))
))
```

That gives `[1505,2530,3024,4578,252,6552,2529,4577,2499,4547,7056]`

So, given the input string, I have to do the same to find the min bitmap, then return true if this number is present in my precalc list.

```js
// Not so golfed 

F=t=>(  
  a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h=0,M=Math.min,
  t=t.split('\n').filter(r=>r.trim()>''), // remove blank lines
  t=t.map(r=>r.slice(M(...t.map(r=>r.search(/\S/))))), // remove blank colums to the left
  t.map((r,i)=>i&1&&[...r] // only odd rows
   .map((_,j)=>j&1&& // only odd columns
      r[j-1]==r[j+1]&t[i-1][j]==t[i+1][j]&r[j-1]=='|' // found a cell
         &&(y=i>>1,x=j>>1,z=y*5,w=x*5, // find bitmaps for 8 rotations/simmetries
            a|=1<<(z+x),e|=1<<(w+y),  
            b|=1<<(4+z-x),f|=1<<(4+w-y),  
            c|=1<<(20-z+x),g|=1<<(20-w+y),  
            d|=1<<(24-z-x),h|=1<<(24-w-y)  
    ))),
   ~[1505,2530,3024,4578,252,6552,2529,4577,2499,4547,7056].indexOf(Math.min(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)) // look for min
)
```

Run snippet to test in Firefox

```js
F=t=>(a=b=c=d=e=f=g=h=0,M=Math.min,
t=t.split('\n').filter(r=>r.trim()>''),
t=t.map(r=>r.slice(M(...t.map(r=>r.search(/\S/))))),
t.map((r,i)=>i&1&&[...r]
.map((_,j)=>j&1&&r[j-1]==r[j+1]&t[i-1][j]==t[i+1][j]&r[j-1]=='|'
&&(y=i>>1,x=j>>1,z=y*5,w=x*5,
a|=1<<(z+x),e|=1<<(w+y),b|=1<<(4+z-x),f|=1<<(4+w-y),c|=1<<(20-z+x),g|=1<<(20-w+y),d|=1<<(24-z-x),h|=1<<(24-w-y)
))),~[1505,2530,3024,4578,252,6552,2529,4577,2499,4547,7056].indexOf(M(a,b,c,d,e,f,g,h)))

s=[...'      \n      \n      \n  2   \n      \n      '],o=7,l=5,k={},t=0

out=[[],[]]

Test=s=>k[s]?0 // filter duplicates, but allow same shape in different position
  :k[s]=(
  p=Array(13).fill(0).map(x=>Array(13).fill(' ')), // build string to test in long format
  s.map((v,i)=>(x=2*(i%7),y=2*(i/7|0),-v&&(
    p[y][x]=p[y][x+2]=p[y+2][x]=p[y+2][x+2]='+',
    p[y][x+1]=p[y+2][x+1]='-',
    p[y+1][x]=p[y+1][x+2]='|'  
  ))),
  s=p.map(r=>r.join('')).join('\n'),
  ok=F(s), // test
  
  out[!ok|0].push('\n'+s+-ok),
  1
)

Fill=(z,p)=>(
  s[p]=2,
  z>l?Test(s):s.forEach((v,i)=>v==' '&(s[i+o]==2|s[i-o]==2|s[i-1]==2|s[i+1]==2)?Fill(z+1,i):0),
  s[p]=' '
)
             
Fill(1,s.indexOf('2')) 

OV.innerHTML=out[0].join('\n')
OI.innerHTML=out[1].join('\n')
```

```css
pre { 
  overflow: auto;
  font-size: 9px;
  height: 500px; 
  display: block; 
  border: 1px solid #888;
  padding: 6px 20px;
  line-height: 6px;
}
```

```html
Verify all hexominoes possible in a 6x6 grid (Better full page) <br>
<table><tr>
  <th>VALID</th><th>INVALID</th>
</tr><tr>
  <td><pre id=OV></pre></td>
  <td><pre id=OI></pre></td>
</tr></table>
```

Comment: Forgive me if I am missing something, but couldn't you the `,\nt=t` from the end of the second line/the beginning of the third line?

Comment: @CᴏɴᴏʀO'Bʀɪᴇɴ reviewing six months later, the parsing code could be made 10...15 bytes shorter. As is, I need the assignment to t in line 2 and the again in line 3 because in line 3 it's used to find the number of blank chars to cut at left side.